# Sendbird error. Command received no ack

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, sendbird

I got `Command received no ack.` error after calling `sendUserMessage` function. Does anybody know the possible reason?

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Comment: hi! now i using next strategy and error is missed:
1. try send message
2. if any error is occured i try to reconnect
3. then try send message again (always executed with success)

Comment: @Skiminock hey can you elaborate on that i ran into same problem? specifically on mobile. Works fine on web but when im on phone it gives me that error. calling sendfileMessage

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following solution which says this is related with method markAsRead
https://community.sendbird.com/t/sendbirdexception-command-received-no-ack/1925/9
This was my solution for this issue

```
this.markAsRead = function () {
            chatGroupChannel.markAsRead(this.markAsReadCallBack);
    };
    this.markAsReadCallBack = function(){
        console.log('markAsReadCallBack exectuted');
    };
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30546752)